# Dadurch, dass vs bei + Verben

Tags: standard-german

> Du kannst dir das Leben dadurch retten, dass du aus dem Fenster hinausspringst.

> Du kannst dir das Leben beim Sprung aus dem Fenster retten.

Kann man **dadurch, dass** durch **bei** ersetzen? Danke!

Comment: Schau noch mal auf das Ende von Beispiel 2: "Du kannst Dir das Leben beim Sprung (...) herausspringen"?

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Ist die Frage allgemein gestellt oder nur auf dieses Beispiel bezogen? Falls allgemein: woher die Vermutung - gibt's da noch mehr Beispiele, die den Eindruck machen dass es geht? Geht es um stilistische Vermeidung von "dadurch, dass"?

Comment: Did you think of English *by*? *By* translates to *durch* in this context. *Durch* can only be followed by nouns (also gerunds), however. If a subclause should follow, you need the "workaround" *dadurch, dass*. So a *dadurch, dass* subclause can often be transformed into a *durch* + gerund construction.

Answer (score 2):

Der Zweite Satz funktioniert mMn nicht.  Es geht höchstens:

> Du kannst dir das Leben **durch einen** Sprung aus dem Fenster retten.

"**Beim**" würde hier **während** heißen